# Combine data from multiple sheets in new excel file

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm new to Excel so I'm sorry if this is newbie question.

I have one excel file with about 30 sheets containing sales for each day of the month for particular products. These sheets are named like "01.01.2022", "02.01.2022", "03.01.2022" and so on.
They are formatted like this
| productID | totalSold|
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 120 |
| 1 | 14 |
| 2 | 300 |

From these multiple sheets I need to add their totalSold values to an existing table that is formatted like this

| productID | 01.01.2022. expected | 01.01.2022. sold | 02.01.2022. expected | 02.01.2022. sold | 03.01.2022. expected | 03.01.2022 sold | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 120 | [dataFromOtherSheet] | 110 | dataFromOtherSheet | 100 | dataFromOtherSheet |  |
| 1 | 14 | [dataFromOtherSheet] | 20 | dataFromOtherSheet | 10 | dataFromOtherSheet |  |

I already have data for "[date] expected" column.
Values in each row for "[date] sold" columns are sum of sales for that product in a given day.
I need to combine data from for example sheet called "01.01.2022" which containes all sales and place those values into column called "01.01.2022 sold". Their productID columns need to match and they are not in the same order in every sheet so I can't just use copy/paste, plus there are a lot of data so it's imposible. All tables in those sheets have same columns, only order of products is different that order in this existing table which contains expected and sold columns.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood right your problem you have to use summifs formula.
Assuming your items code are in A column and your item price are on B column   you could write :
=summIfs('01.01.2022'!B:B;'01.01.2022'!A:A; A1)